# How do I convert varchar to float in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Column 1 which is varchar and Column 2 which is float.
I want to copy the contents of Column 1 to Column 2 for all instances where it looks like Column 1 has a number.

Here's my code:

```
UPDATE [TestDB].[dbo].data
SET [COLUMN 2]=CAST( [Column 1] AS FLOAT)
WHERE ISNUMERIC ([COLUMN 1]) = 1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.  Should this code work?

Comment: What is the value that is failing?

Comment: TomTom, I disagree.  I'm looking for situations where it can be...I added ISNUMERIC..

Comment: @phan It won't necessarily work. Try this: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('-')`, and now try `SELECT CAST('-' AS FLOAT)`

Comment: I've seen situations similar to yours where the cast is performed before the where clause so that it would error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE [TestDB].[dbo].data
SET [COLUMN 2]=Case When IsNumeric([Column 1]) = 1 Then CAST( [Column 1] AS FLOAT) End
```

Comment: G Mastros, thanks I just added the ISNUMERIC line and you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this

```
case when isnumeric([Column 1])=1 
         then cast([Column 1] AS FLOAT)
         else 0
end
```

> ISNUMERIC ( expression )  Determines whether an expression is a valid
>   numeric type.

see here [ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933213%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)